# Changing shell for root

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I've been following [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh-on-linux/#step-install-and-configure-zsh) to switch my shell to zhs. However when I get to running this:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root
```

I get the following error:

```
You may not change the shell for 'root'.
```

Is this intended to happen or am I get something wrong? Should I not be changing my root's shell?

Comment: In the guide you linked, commands are all issued from a root shell (hence they use `apt install zsh` instead of `sudo apt install zsh` for example). Did you do the same? Otherwise, yes it is intended to happen (a non-privileged user should not be able to change root's - or anybody else's except their own - login shell)

Comment: I did not realise that had to be run with root, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Changing shell for root is generally something I wouldn't do. If something happens during an update, or if you decide to switch shell again, you may find yourself in a bad situation. I would recommend to always have root use the default shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but I would strongly advise against it: If anything goes horribly wrong, you can't log in as root anymore. Please consider that the *zsh* package is not installed by default, and IIRC it's also not by default in `/etc/shells` (I might be wrong there). You might get into situations where the shell that you configured for root is not available.

I love zsh, but for my root account I *always* leave the default *bash*. When I need to work as root for more than a handful of commands, I simply do

```
sudo zsh
```

and hey presto, I am root with my favourite *zsh*.

Comment: I second this. Changing the default shell for root adds an unnecessary point of failure, should something go wrong in the future. I would highly recommend staying on Bash for root as default.

Answer (score 0):

You should log in by a root user (from the terminal):

- Type `su` or `sudo su`.
- Run the command `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root`.